# UML diagram for page transitions in the UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, uml

I am working on an asp.net Webforms web application and I am trying to simplify the UI for better usability. I want to visualize the complex page transitions for various things within the system so that they are all documented. What is the UML diagram that I should be using in this case?

Based on my search online, I think creating UML State diagrams is the answer, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486093/a-diagram-for-procedural-php-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you just look to the question asked some days ago ? "A diagram for Procedural PHP pages?".

It is the same question and yes "usually" this is modeled with a state machine.

Note that you can use an activity diagram also. But this is less convenient to say that an activity is a screen (because a screen does nothing) than to say that a screen is a step. A screen could be seen as a step in a function for which several screens are needed.

Comment: Didn't see that question. Thanks! I started creating UML State diagrams in Visio.