# What diagram can I use to show Html Events and Actions

Tags: html, events, uml, diagram

I want to design User Control flow of HTML elements (like enabled/Disabled drop-down box) as shown in diagram.[image]

This is a rough Diagram, but I want to use a **formal approch.**

What Diagram could I use??

**Need :**

1. I want this way of representing to avoid redundancy in coding.
2. Also, tomorrow if my need to change my code, I could easily refer this diagram.

And, My Diagram should include **condition checking too.**

Example : Enable the text-box only when drop-box value is "others".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660828/is-there-a-visual-diagram-format-for-gui-event-mapping

Comment: @nakosspy Ya! I searched a lot., but never saw that question. ya its a duplicate. I agree.

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611881/is-uml-state-machine-diagram-can-be-used-to-show-the-screen-navigation

Answer (score 0):

The closer to what you want to do sounds like a UML sequence diagram. You can use conditions there as well. As regarding how much this will allow you to avoid redudancy in your code, I believe that good modeling lead to better coding, so do the diagram and then I guess you will have a better way to implement your code.